# A bounded function, which has a primitive function, that is not continuous in more that a finite number of points?

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for an example of a function that is bounded on a compact interval and has a primitive function, but that is not continuous on that same interval in more than just a finite number of points?, i.e.:

- $f(x)$ bounded on $[a,b]$
- $F'(x) = f(x)$ on $[a,b]$
- $f(x)$  not continuous on $[a,b]$ in more than just a finite number of points

Comment: Since you deleted a related post, I wanted to clear up a confusion you may have: having an antiderivative (a primitive) is *not* the same thing as being Lebesgue Integrable... It's the same thing as being Henstock-Kurzweil Integrable, and you get weaker properties. Iirc you need something like discontinuities of Lebesgue measure zero for the existence of a primitive to imply Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: That wasn't really the question, but I guess a good point nonetheless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could restrict [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) to a suitable domain.
Note that a bounded function $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann-integrable iff $f$ is continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: V is differentiable everywhere, the derivative V ′ is bounded everywhere, the derivative is not Riemann-integrable. Good point, V ′ is precisley that function.

Comment: Exactly. Glad I could help.